# Real Time procedure

Tags: php, c, linux, real-time, google-ads-api

I have platform written in PHP that is synced with Google Adwords API.
I need my server to repeatedly check values from the Adwords database then update my database.
I think this could be done via cronjob but the problem is running a php cron every 5 minutes that sends request to google server might trash the CPU and consume a lot of memory.
I came up with an idea of making it with C language which is very light and won't consume much memory.

The syncing process should run regardless users visiting the PHP script, for that reason I came up with cronjob at the first place.

My question is how should I approach this issue? is cronjob the right solution?
If is, should it be done with C? I'd probably need a Soap Client library, can you please recommend of one?

Thanks a lot,
Oron

Comment: I doubt a cron-job running every 5 minutes is going to be a performance problem

Comment: Despite running a php script that perform database manipulation with soap requests?

Comment: Yes, have you seen any evidence that would suggest that it would be a problem?  Modern applications make database and and web (soap, rest, etc.) calls constantly, usually with much higher frequency then 5 minutes.

Comment: Say I have about 1000 queries to make along with 1000 soap requests, would it still be fine (assuming done with a PHP script & apache).

Comment: If it's going to be that excessive, I would look into optimizing the number of requests being made, using C instead of PHP isn't the issue here as to me I would be concerned about IO, not CPU.